# Dynamic gradle copy task not executing task body

Tags: gradle, build, copy, task

Below script generates a dynamic copy task(cbat).
But executing

> gradle cbat

only executes

> copyFiles

method definition (only println statements), but don't copy files from source to destination directory.

Please find below simplified build.gradle :-

```
group 'learn'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

task fileCopy{
    group 'Config'
    description 'Copy task'
    ext.scriptSrc = 'C:\\Users\\devuser\\Desktop\\jars\\src\\binwin'
    ext.scriptDest = 'C:\\Users\\devuser\\Desktop\\jars\\dest'
    ext.includeEmptyDirs = false

    //This adds a cbat gradle task
    copyFiles("cbat", scriptSrc, scriptDest, "*.bat", includeEmptyDirs)
}


def copyFiles(String taskName, String source, String dest, String pattern, boolean includeEmptyDirs = false){
    println "$taskName"
    println "$source"
    println "$dest"
    println "$pattern"
    println "$includeEmptyDirs"

    task "$taskName" (type:org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy) << {
        includeEmptyDirs = includeEmptyDirs
        FileCollection collection = fileTree(source).include(pattern)
        from( collection )
        into dest
    }
}
```

I already verified that the source and destination directories exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call 'execute()' to run the task, like this:

```
task copyFiles<<{
    task ([type:Copy], 'name'){
        println this.name
    }.execute()
}
```